# Puzzling difference of variadic template method behavior for templated and non templated classes

Tags: c++, c++11

I am scratching my head with a strange problem highlighted by the following minimal code:

```
struct A {
    template <typename ...X, typename ...Y>
    void f(X... a, Y...b) {
    }

    template <typename ...X>
    void g(X...c) {
       f<X...> (c...);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct B {
    template <typename ...X, typename ...Y>
    void f(X... a, Y...b) {
    }

    template <typename ...X>
    void g(X...c) {
       f<X...> (c...);
    }
};



int main() {
    A a;
    a.g(); // Compiles without problem

    B<int> b;
    b.g(); // Compiler complains saying g() calls f<>() with 0 arguments while 1 is expected
}
```

Both g++ and clang++ give the same basic error messages for the second case. 
They basically say that the call to f() within the templated class needs one argument.

Is this a bug in both compilers, or am I missing something in the C++ standard?

Comment: `clang` from trunk also borks on the first version.

Comment: Interesting. So is such a method or function illegal in the standard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method taking two parameter packs is illegal according to 14.1 [temp.param] paragraph 11:

> ... A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list
>   of the function template or has a default argument (14.8.2). [ Example:

```
template<class T1 = int, class T2> class B; // error
// U cannot be neither deduced from the parameter-type-list nor specified
template<class... T, class... U> void f() { } // error
template<class... T, class U> void g() { } // error
```

> —end example ]

Comment: The diagnostics I have seen so far from `clang` and `gcc` are outright wrong. It seems reasonable that this is not allowed.

Comment: @pmr: Yeah, it's strange that Clang has such weird `note:`s attached to the errors, and that it compiles the code at all when `f` isn't called.

Comment: The example you show is understandable but if U is passed, it can be deduced so it should be legal in such a case. But I can see that my example is asking for trouble. 
It sounds like the compiler should also complain about the case for struct A.

Comment: @Michel: How can you ever pass `U`? All arguments will be swallowed by `T` (and `X` and `a` in the question's code).

Comment: @Xeo: template <class ... T, class U...> void f(U...) {} // unambiguous U from the list of arguments
From what Dietmar wrote, it should be legal "unless that template parameter can be deduced from the parapeter-type-list of the function template

Comment: @Michel: Yes, `U` can in that case be deduced. But it can't in the example from the standard, and the same goes for `Y` in the question's code.

Comment: @Xeo: I do agree now that I have rethought how f<X...>(c...) is matched against the declaration. I can solve my need by creating a helper class templated on X... and that defines a method/static function f(X...,Y...)

Comment: @Michel: Why do you even need that? Why doesn't one pack suffice? `X` and `Y` will contain exactly the same arguments in your code.

Comment: @Xeo, I have a method that is called with variadiadic argument. It then calls a recursive method that unpacks some other object into additional arguments, but at the end of the recursion, I need to be able to distinguish the original arguments from the one unpacked by my recursion.

Comment: I take back all I said.. I forgot what the exact resolution of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1275 was ... indeed the words "from the parameter-type-list" are very important here :)